# enable dropdown on checkbox checked not working... Dropdown is not getting enabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, isenabled

I am trying to enable dropdown when the checkbox is checked. But when I do so... It didn't working. Pls help me out here. 
HTML :

```
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" value="" id="onstage">On Stage
              </label>


                      <div class="col-md-9">
                       <select name="occupation" id="occupation" multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
                        <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
                        <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
                    </select>
```

JQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

            $("#onstage").click(function(){

                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $("#occupation").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#occupation").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#occupation").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: 3.2.1 version @B.Desai

Comment: works fine for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery `3.2.1` then your code must work.

Check once

1) You don't have error in other js code(check console for error)

2) Make sure id must be unique so you must have `onstage` and `occupation` only one time in document

```js
 $(function(){

            $("#onstage").click(function(){

                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $("#occupation").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#occupation").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#occupation").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" id="onstage">On Stage
</label>


<div class="col-md-9">
 <select name="occupation" id="occupation" multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
  <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** as per your comment you are using `bootstrap multiselect` So you need to enable and disable `multiselect` attribute chcgae your code like this:

```
$("#onstage").click(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $("#occupation").multiselect('enable');                    
 } else {
         $("#occupation").multiselect('disable');
 }
});
```

Comment: I have also added suggestion have checked it?

Comment: Is it available on dom load? or check box is added dynamically(like by AJAX)?

Comment: checkbox is in html

Comment: i've used bootstrap multiselect for dropdown list to show checkbox in it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prop` instead of `attr` for setting `disabled` property, [if you're using jQuery 1.6+](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/). Also you can simplify your code like this:

```
$("#onstage").change(function(){
   $("#occupation").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));

    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("#occupation").focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $("#occupation").attr("disabled", "true");  in else block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

            $("#onstage").click(function(){debugger;

                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $("#occupation").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#occupation").focus();
                } else {
                    $("#occupation").attr("disabled", "true");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to remove selected value at the time of uncheck checkbox, you can use this:

```js
$("#onstage").click(function(){
   $("#occupation").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked")).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="onstage"/> On Stage
</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="occupation" id="occupation" multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
        <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
    </select>
</div>
```